# Fecha Automatizada

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente duda: ¿Cómo poner una fecha automática en SQL Server o en C#?

Por ejemplo en este *query*:

```
SELECT id,Registration FROM tbl_CRs
WHERE Registration BETWEEN '20170201' AND '20170216'
and [Status]='OPEN'
```

En C# sería algo así:

```
string query = "SELECT id,Registration FROM tbl_CRs WHERE Registration BETWEEN '" + LblMes.Text + "' and '"+LblHoy.Text+"' ";
```

Como se habrán dado cuenta puse la fecha de hoy, hace una comparación del primer día de este mes, pero cuando sea Marzo, quiero que haga una comparación del primer día de Marzo, y así sucesivamente. Quiero que el primer parámetro que declaro en el `where` se cambie al primer día de los meses futuros.

Comment: en c# sería new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year,DateTime.Now.Month,1) para el primer día del mes y DateTime.Now para el día actual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que pides es realizar una consulta que traiga valores entre el primer día del mes actual y la fecha actual. Para SQL quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT Id, Registration 
FROM tbl_CRs
WHERE Registration BETWEEN DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AND GETDATE()
AND [Status] = 'OPEN'
```

Para C# quedaría:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    string query = "SELECT Id, Registration FROM tbl_CRs WHERE Registration BETWEEN @PrimerDiaMes AND @FechaActual";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PrimerDiaMes", new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1));
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FechaActual", DateTime.Now);
    conn.Open();
    var result = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (result.Read())
    {
        //Código con el resultado obtenido
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

Te recomiendo dejar de usar el armado de *queries* dinámico (como lo pones en tu ejemplo), es suceptible a Inyección SQL, [aquí la documentación oficial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx) para las mejores prácticas al respecto.

Answer (score 1):

También lo puedes hacer directamente desde una instrucción de SQL:

```
"SELECT id,Registration FROM tbl_CRs WHERE Registration BETWEEN DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0) and convert(date,getdate())"
```

Toma en consideración de que en la manera en que lo pudieras estar haciendo, causaría problemas de inyección de sql.

Comment: Gracias Juan, tengo una pregunta , si quiero saber los` id` que sean menores a 60 días después de su `registration`, y otra consulta para lo que sean mayores a 60 días después de su `registration`, (<60, y >60)

Comment: Sólo hay que colocar la condición siguiente 
`WHERE DATEDIFF(day,Registration,getdate()) < 60` y 
`WHERE DATEDIFF(day,Registration,getdate()) >= 60` y

Answer (score 0):

justo hoy me enfrente a un problema similar al tuyo la manera en la que lo pude resolver fue de la siguiente:

c# ya trae librerías para el tiempo así que las use y se las asigne a una variable de tipo string.

```
string FechaInicial = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

asi me trae el resultado tal como lo acepta el date de sql (año-mes-dia)

y para la fecha final use:

```
string FechaFinal= DateTime.Today.ToString();
```

y ya armas la consulta que en tu caso seria:

```
string query = "SELECT id,Registration FROM tbl_CRs WHERE Registration BETWEEN '" + FechaIncial+ "' and '"+FechaFinal+"' ";
```

Espero te sirva la explicación :) saludos!.

Answer (score 0):

c#

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var startOfMonth = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1).ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

en la consulta concatenas la variable startOfMonth a tu consulta sql.